# What does Dominant pole/Pole mean related to capacitors and filters or Electronics in general for intuitive understanding

Tags: control-loop, pole-compensation

I am trying to understand the feedback compensation techniques of DC-DC Buck converters. And I drift to more and more small questions which make me want to understand the basics of poles/zeroes/frequency

[In this link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66249/single-pole-amplifier) the answer given by user Kaz, in the last para, "One way in which amplifiers with multiple poles are stabilized is with the help of capacitors which create a "dominant pole" whose frequency roll-off is so great that the poles at higher frequencies basically do not matter (the gain is squashed at those frequencies). The amplifier basically "looks" like a single pole one."

I can't able to understand what he is saying in the last para. I know, it is somewhat easy. But i am not able grasp

In general, can someone clarify me the concept of pole, dominant pole with filters/capacitors?
Like, if someone says, there is a pole in the feedback loop, or two poles in the loop, how to understand it electrically? one more question regarding this, i understand that if there is a pole, it means that oscillations will be present in the system. But the oscillations will be at what frequency? Will it be at the resonant frequency of the part or the entire systems?

Experts who find mistakes in my question, please let me know where I am wrong.

I also find a single pole and double pole loops. How do they arise?

It would be better if someone can provide me an analogy regarding these poles/frequency for good understanding.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand what a bode plot is? Did you fully comprehend [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/449489/poles-and-zeros-of-a-transfer-function) to one of your earlier questions?

Comment: Yes. I understand the bode plot

Comment: Does [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/275362/what-is-the-difference-between-frequency-response-and-transfer-function?noredirect=1&lq=1) help?

Comment: I tried to understand ur answer but I'm unable to understand it mathematically. So, I started to understand your answer in the electrical sense. Since, the question was not related to electrical, I wanted to ask it in a different way. I am trying to understand the concept with less mathematics and more of how this (Poles/Zeroes) means in the electrical domain. I also understand that, if the system has a pole, then it will oscillate infinitely. if it doesn't, output will be zero. But i want to understand at what frequency will the system oscillate? And what does single/double pole mean?

Comment: Just to correct misunderstanding: a system that has a pole will not oscillate. A system that has two poles may oscillate but certainly won't definitely oscillate.

Comment: I read that answer of yours too. But the thing is that, all the answers are tending to be more of mathematical and less of electrical. I too understand that these systems can be understood mathematically mostly. But I am trying to get the concept and the relation between the math and electrical. What do you mean when you say "2nd order LPF" in electrical terms? I know LPF and how it works. But what makes and LPF "2nd order". I understand 2nd order is related to differential equations. So, need some relation between that math and electrical in more electrical terms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96895/discussion-between-newbie-and-andy-aka).

Comment: Poles and zeroes are all about math.

Comment: https://www.microchip.com/stellent/groups/SiteComm_sg/documents/Training_Tutorials/en527885.pdf. Could u explain me the first para on page 5. How is it 2 pole feedback loop and the other is one pole feedback loop in electrical terms?

Comment: The trouble is that you are jumping in at the deep end and trying to understand pole/zero as applied to feedback loops. You should study single order filters then 2nd order filters and from that you will understand resonance and from that you should understand pole/zero for a system that has no feedback hence can't oscillate. Then you will start to be able to make the bigger leap to applying all that when there is feedback.

Comment: Ok. Could you just help me with that one para mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: Are you talking about the para that begins "current mode..."? If you are then given that your understanding is sketchy and I don't know where you have good knowledge or weaker knowledge in those areas, it would be too problematic. Try and focus on what you know and ask questions that take you to the next level rather than jump too far.

Comment: yes, it is that para. Ok. Could you just explain these two terms - "one pole feedback loop" & " two pole feedback loop" in electrical terms?

Comment: Do you know what electrically is the difference between 1 pole and 2 poles. I'm talking here about circuits i.e. what would be the difference in the circuits?

Comment: no. I donot understand whats the difference electrically. could you provide me with an example please

Comment: You need to look at simple RC low pass filters then look at RLC low pass filters. RC and 1st order and RLC are 2nd order but, remember this isn't a forum and if you get stuck here I'd encourage you to ask a new question.

Comment: Newbie --- as you learn, examine Vout = G(mag,phase) / [1 + G(mag,phase) * H(mag,phase)] for large and small "mag" and for large and small "phase".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You keep trying to understand it "more electrically", but the problem is that pole dominance, and the pole concept itself, is strictly related to Laplace Transform (LT) theory, which is a strong mathematical theory.

Poles are not an "electrical concept" in itself. It is a concept that can be applied to any linear system, or any system amenable to be linearized usefully for the application at hand. They can be electrical systems, but also mechanical, thermal or systems in whatever field of application you may imagine where the LT techniques can be applied.

Chu already gave you a very simplified view of the concept in the time domain for an electrical system. I'll try to dumb down the things some more, but keep in mind that if you don't want to grok some math, it is really not possible to understand the concept in all its depth.

First of all, poles are related to how fast a system can react when it is excited, and the reaction time is related to how the system can store and release energy during and after the excitation.

An (idealized) system which cannot store energy has no reaction time, it reacts immediately to any stimulus it is subjected to (think of a pure resistive circuit, where resistors are ideal). Reaction time for electrical circuits, therefore, depends on elements that can store energy: reactive elements, that is capacitors and inductors (if we keep the things simple and don't consider mutual induction and/or distributed circuits).

Grossly simplifying, each ***independent*** reactive element contributes a pole to the circuit, and the number of poles of a system is called the ***order of the system***. So a circuit with one cap and no inductors is a 1st order system. A circuit with a cap and an inductor is a 2nd order system (or two independent caps), and so on.

What does it mean "independent" element? Too complex for you, if you don't want to grok the math, so let's skip it. Very broadly, it means that the level of energy storage of one element is completely independent from the level of the other elements.

OK, now what do the poles do to a system? They describe the "reaction time***s***" of the system. Note the plural! A system that is excited momentarily (imagine a fast electrical impulse) reacts with a response that evolve in time and then dies off (if the system is stable).

This "impulse response" is made up of different components, each of which decays with a different ***time constant***. Every pole contributes a different component with a different time constant. The time constant is a measure of how fast a component decays: the bigger the time constant, the slower the component decay (usually a component is considered zero after 5 time constants have elapsed, actually the decay lasts forever theoretically since it is exponential -- see Chu's answer for a simple math expression).

The impulse response of a stable system dies off after a while and the time it takes to die off gives you an estimate of the reaction time of the system: the time a system needs to stabilize into a new condition when the inputs are varied.

A dominant pole is a pole whose time constant is much "slower", i.e. bigger, than all the other time constants of the circuit, therefore the corresponding component is still observable after all the other, faster decaying, components have died off.

In other words, a system with a dominant pole behaves approximately like a 1st order system, i.e. a system that has a single pole.

In the end, the concept of pole dominance is a way to simplify a system: if a dominant pole exists, with some caveats, the system can be thought as a 1st order system, i.e. the simplest system imaginable that has a non-trivial time evolution.

The problem is that not every system has a dominant pole, so it can't be simplified that way. A technique used sometimes to simplify things is to *add a compensating network* in the circuit, i.e. a network containing at least one reactive element, in order to ***introduce* a dominant pole in the system** and thus allowing the simplification.

Of course, if you want to introduce a new pole in the system that has to be dominant, its time constant must be bigger of any existing pole (unless you do pole-zero cancellation, but that is a still nastier and more advanced technique), therefore you end-up slowing down the system. So it's often a kind of trade-off: you slow down a fast system in order to make it simpler, i.e. more manageable by the rest of the control chain. In the process you lose something (e.g. fast response or gain) in order to gain something else (e.g. stability or accuracy).

Note that my answer contains lots of hand-waving and gross conceptual simplifications, but everything I've said can be justified and expanded mathematically to give the exact definition and interpretation of what is a pole and what is a dominant pole. The problem is, as I've already said, that you can't escape the heavy math then.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer which I can understand and get some real good clarity. Very grateful to you, sir.

Comment: In the S-plane, we have poles on the left and right side. What do they mean ? Can you please clarify with the location of poles and the freq wrto s plane?

Comment: This is a very good way to overview the concept of dominate pole and pole before jumping into the NISE Control System book which gets murky with math. Nevertheless it a best over simplified explanation that should take place in NISE book for a starter!

Answer (score 3):

Dominance is most easily explained in the time domain.

Consider a transfer function: \$\small G(s)=\large \frac{5}{(s+1)(s+5)}\$, with a unit step applied, giving the step response: \$\small C(s)=\large \frac{5}{s(s+1)(s+5)}\$.

Expanding this function in partial fractions:

$$\small C(s)= \frac{1}{s}-\frac{1.25}{s+1}+\frac{0.25}{s+5}$$

And the time response is:

$$\small c(t)=1-1.25e^{-t/1}+0.25e^{-t/0.2} $$

So the transient has two terms, one with a time constant, \$\small \tau=1\$ sec, and the other with a time constant, \$\small \tau=0.2\$ sec. But the faster transient has  much smaller residue: (\$\small 0.25\$) compared to the slower transient (\$\small 1.25\$). If you sketch the step response you'll see that it is dominated by the slower transient.

This illustrates the general rule that poles that are closer to the s-plane origin are more dominant than those that are more distant. In this particular case, the pole that is five times faster is five times smaller in magnitude.

To relate this to the frequency domain, we note that the effects of the faster poles (higher 3dB frequencies or resonant frequencies) are more apparent close to \$\small t=0\$, and the slower poles (lower 3dB frequencies or resonant frequencies) are  more apparent at larger values of \$\small t\$.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand. Can you tell me in more electrical terms? Like how when we say Single pole, Double pole and all, how does it relate electrically? Like what cause two poles? What does two poles mean in electrical terms? And oscillation occurs at the poles, what will be frequency of oscillation? Can you please relate my questions electrically to get an intuitive understanding for clarity.

Comment: I just addressed the headline question. Relating it to specific electrical networks is a more extensive answer that I do not have time to do presently, but I may extend the answer later.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But I want to understand this concept more electrically.

Comment: Again good explanation. It all very clear now. If you look into the s-plane in relation to capacitor and inductor, you can see how the open-loop equation of the plant G(s) is formed. Tip: Consider cap and inductor circuit as a plant which formed into G(s) equation (open loop).